# How to get user destination by code in c#

Tags: c#, google-maps, asp.net-mvc-4

My project is: asp.net mvc4

Idea is next: I have 3 google engines by which I parse google response. Engines is google.com, google.ru, google.co.uk. Have any method to get user destination and display google engine based on their destination, forexample if my user from russia I make search from google.ru, if user from UK im work with google.co.uk and for others I'm use google.co.uk. May I check this programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this service to find the location of the user using the IP address.http://freegeoip.net/. You can use their API

http://freegeoip.net/json/115.113.234.46.

It returns a JSON response as follows.

```
{
   "ip": "115.113.234.46",
    "country_code": "IN",
    "country_name": "India",
    "region_code": "",
    "region_name": "",
    "city": "",
    "zipcode": "",
    "latitude": 20,
    "longitude": 77,
    "metro_code": "",
    "areacode": ""
}
```

Then parse it to obtain the location.But it may not be accurate always.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IP address-based lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_location) to determine the location of your users.

http://www.hostip.info/ is a free service (but has gaps in its database) and http://www.maxmind.com/en/home offers a paid-for service.

Alternatively, modern browsers have a [geolocation API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3C_Geolocation_API) you can access via JavaScript. If you use this then your users will be prompted by their browser to allow your website to access their location (which they might decline).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is not exactly what I can be use inside in my c# code.